# refresh form after button click

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ado.net

I'm getting the first element of a table articles  where  column(statusArticle=false).The problem is that i want to refresh the form after the button click so i can interact with next element, but the form is not refreshed, i tried several codes exept the one of application.restart that is heavy! How can i refresh the form at the boutton click without restarting application?

```
   private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (DbEntities db = new DbEntities())
            {
               Articles firstArticle = db.Articles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.statusArticle == false);
                if (firstArticle != null)
                {
                    firstArticle.statusArticle = true;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    MessageBox.Show("Article validated", "OK");
                    this.Refresh();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen on a "refresh"?

Comment: Can you try to use `Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);'

Comment: @nvoigt, on a refresh, i expect that the value of firstArticle will be changed to the next(firstArticle), since the old(firstArticle).statusArticle!=false.

Comment: You probably wrote code to show the first article on your form. Maybe you can call that again?

Comment: The Refresh method on the Form class invalidates the client area and forces a redraw of the form and will not re-populate the properties of the controls. You should create a method that will take the first article and populate the form controls, then call that instead of "this.Refresh()".

Comment: @nvoigt I showed the first article in a textBox, i wrote the code in public Form {} after initialize.compenent().. but i don't know how to call that again??

Comment: Take the code from the constructor and place it into a method. Then call that method from the constructor and replace the call to "this.Refresh()".

Comment: @MotoSV How can i create that method please?

Comment: private void ShowArticle(Article article) { /* code goes here */ }

Comment: @MotoSV it's my first week with c# how can i create this method please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your class create the following:

```
private void ShowArticle(Article article)
{
  /* The code currently in your constructor for displaying the 
     first article goes here */
}
```

For your constructor:

```
public MyForm()
{
  using(DbEntities db = new DbEntities())
  {
    Articles firstArticle = db.Articles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.statusArticle == false);
    if( firstArticle != null ) ShowArticle( firstArticle );
  }
}
```

In your button click handler instead of calling Refresh simple replace it with a call to ShowArticle passing in "firstArticle". The code above could be cleaned up a bit, but it should do.